# How to configure OpenShift router for KeyCloak?

Tags: openshift, keycloak, netflix-zuul

I have created two projects in OpenShift.

```
browser ---> apps/router ---> apps/gw ---> apps
   \                                \
    \                        (/auth) \---> kc/router ---> kc
     \                                     ^
      \-----------------------------------/
           (kc login page)
```

The first project (*apps*) contains a microservice application and also has a gateway implemented using Netflix Zuul proxy. The second project (*kc*) has a running KeyCloak instance that can also be reached from outside via a configured route.

Zuul proxy in *apps* has a route from */auth* to *kc/auth*.

The UI uses the KeyCloak adapter for authentication. When I call *apps/ui* the SPA is fetched and I'm redirected to *apps/auth* for authentication. After giving username/password I should be redirected back to the UI but it does not work. I get an error page with an URL pointing to *kc*. In KeyCloak log I get the following entry:

`10:15:24,969 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=NUSS, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.3.47.12, error=invalid_code`

I found out from KeyCloak docu that there has to be something wrong with proxy configuration. When I call *apps/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration* all URLs are pointing to *kc*. In the docu section about proxy configuration it says that this response should actually contain URLs to *apps*.

I think that the route to KeyCloak configured in *kc* replaces the *x-forwarded-host* header and other proxy headers with *kc* instead of just leaving the headers set already set in *apps*. I already validated that the request leaving Zuul proxy contains the correct proxy forwarding headers.

I now have several questions:

- What do I have to do to have KeyCloak work in a separate project?
- Is my analysis correct anyway?
- How can I eventually configure the route in *kc* to not replace the proxy headers?
- Is there eventually a best practice how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. But I did have to install a custom router configuration ([Deploying a Customized HAProxy Router](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/router/customized_haproxy_router.html)). I configured that the *x-forwarded-host* and and *x-forwarded-port* headers are passing the router untouched if present.

```
  # preserve X-Forwarded-Host Header if already set
  acl no_xhost res.hdr(X-Forwarded-Host) -m len 0
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(host)] if no_xhost

  # preserve X-Forwarded-Port Header if already set
  acl no_xport res.hdr(X-Forwarded-Port) -m len 0
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] if no_xport
```

I also had to set the following property in Zuul config.

```
zuul.add-proxy-headers=true
```

I wonder why the default router config does overwrite the headers anyway.
Generally I would say that if a request passes various reverse proxies the proxy headers should not be changed while passing them. Otherwise the service at the end of the chain can never know what URL has been used for the original request. Right?